# Arquillian and wildfly - how to start in standalone-full?

Tags: gradle, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

My project configuration is Arquillian with Gradle and Wildfly 10 CR4. I have changed the standalone.conf in wildfly to use standalone-full.xml by default. Unfortunately Arquillian seems starting the embedded wildfly using standalone.xml. I guess I need to change a different file for the embedded server since is not a 'standalone' but I cannot find it.

Comment: could you please share your gradle file, I need to activate arquillian with gradle for wildfly 9, but still have problem with it.

Answer (score 5):

In arquillian.xml add property serverConfig

```
<property name="serverConfig">standalone-full.xml</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it. it is configurable adding this in gradle:

systemProperty 'jboss.server.default.config', 'standalone-full.xml'

Answer (score 0):

In the latest WildFly 22.0.0.Final and the latest WildFly Arquillian 3.0.1.Final, the `serverConfig` config in failsafe plugin does not work as expected here.

I have tried under Windows 10/Java 11(AdoptOpenJDK)  and a CI env(Ubuntu/AdoptOpenJDK).

Finally, I checked some configurations from WildFly testsuite, and set a system property in the maven failsafe plugin to overcome this issue.

```xml
<jboss.server.config.file.name>standalone-full.xml</jboss.server.config.file.name>
```